# How to autosave a formControlName using Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, autosave

I have this TextField in .html

```
<TextField class="textfield" row="0" col="1" formControlName="powersupplyid" [text]='myipdevice'> </TextField>
```

I want to autosave this function when 'myipdevice' display in view.

```
getform() {
    ..........
     .....
        this.myipdevice = myipfind;
        console.log('u gjet', this.myipdevice)
        let LS = require("nativescript-localstorage");
        LS.setItem(this.myipdevice);
    }
```

Can you ask me any idea how to autosave value `myipdevice` whene data show in html?

Thank you!

Comment: You should provide more code, e.g. the component backing this view.

Comment: I have a function that return `myipdevice`. How to autosave this myipdevice when In show in form?

Comment: @Knelis I edit my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it is already being saved into your form object, whatever you called it..
lets say you called it "form"

then `this.form.controls.powersupplyid.value` should have it's value updated automatically whenever you type or do anything inside the textarea

Comment: @new_user I'm still not sure what you want to happen.. do you want to update the localstorage value to update it's saved value every time user updates the TextField value?

Comment: Yes, I want there

Answer (score 0):

Right now you appear to be doing two things. On the one hand you are binding the `TextField` to a reactive form field with `formControlName`, on the other hand you are also binding the `[text]` property. I would suggest to use only `formControlName`.

In your component you can then push the value to the control once it has been retrieved. (Since you haven't posted the full code, I'm making some assumptions here.)

So in the `ngOnInit` method in the example, you can retrieve the saved value from storage. Then update your `FormGroup` with [`patchValue`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value) to push the change to the view.

Additionally, you can listen to changes to the control by subscribing to `valueChanges`.

```
export class IpDeviceFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form: this.fb.group({
    powersupplyid: [''] // this is the FormControl bound to your TextField
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // get a previously saved value from somewhere
    getSavedPowerSupplyId().subscribe(id => {
      this.form.patchValue({
        powersupplyid: id
      });
    });

    // listen for any changes to the form
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(form => { /* Save new form state */ });
  }
}
```